# Joomla 4 add background image to article

Tags: templates, css, images

I cant figure out what im doing wrong. My goal is add background picture to article. I created `custom.css` file with simple code

```
.main-page-picture {
  background-image: url('/images/main_foto_final.jpg');
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

`<link href` for css file is in `<head>` tag.

picture no show whe i add this to source code in article:

```
<div>
     <p class="main-page-picture">Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your question.  I feel we need a bit more debugging detail in this question.  Please [edit] your question to show us the relevant portions of your rendered source code (from in your browser).  We'll want to see that the css file is actually being linked as intended, and that the targeted `<p>` tag exists in the html document.  Your browser's developer tools should go along way in assisting with these clarifying points.

Comment: An additional check that you can do is find the targeted element on your webpage, right click it, Inspect it, then manually add your desired stylings directly in the browser.  Finally, we'll need to verify that your image file exists and that it exists at the path that you've written.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-page-picture {
background-image: url('/images/main_foto_final.jpg');
background-size:cover;
}
```